# jquery ajax error!

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**SOLVED in the last answer**

im getting following error, dunno where and why? cause code works fine and i dont know what is wrong, please suggest something :$

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Line 0
```

why code and functionality works totally fine, even when this error show.. but it dont work in ie, so i need to fix this.

following is the callback function that runs when error shows;

```
built_list: function (response)
 { 
  var parent_id = 0;
  var selected_id = 0; 

  var breadCrump_count = response.bread_crump.length;

  if (breadCrump_count > 1)
   parent_id = response.bread_crump[(breadCrump_count-2)].album_id;

  $("#album_listing_selected_parent").val(parent_id);

  ......
  }

  $("#album_listing").jScrollPane({showArrows:true, scrollbarWidth:20, arrowSize:15, reinitialiseOnImageLoad:true, wheelSpeed: 28});
 },
```

**Edited:**

im using firefox
this bug i got is in firebug

i just try testing some stuff and i actually commented all the built_list inside code and the error still show, so its not inside built_list, BUT error trigger after we get ajax response. i have some other ajax on the application, which works fine, but this one shows this error. im still confuse, im gonna check what is doing before it sends to ajax.  actually following is the code that makes the ajax call

```
$(".view_sub_album").live('click', function() {
        album.get_list(album.getID(this), 0);       
        //$("#album_listing > ul").html('<li></li>'); // empty for new selected albums  
        return false;
    });
```

**Edited Again:**
if i remove the following line, then the error hides and yes the error is exactly same as i wrote in start, which was from firebug. anyway i think jScrollPan overrights clicks! or soemthing.. cause when i removed the jScrollPan  line, it dont give error anymore.

```
$("#album_listing").jScrollPane({showArrows:true, scrollbarWidth:20, arrowSize:15, reinitialiseOnImageLoad:true, wheelSpeed: 28});
```

Comment: What I tend to do, if I figure it out, is to pick the answer of the person whose suggestion helped me the most to determine the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**after lots of test and debugging, the answer is:**

you have to get the jscrollPan from the svn source code and not the old release from the download section, because old version dont have fix and links inside the Scoller start giving the above error. sorry guys, its stupid thing, but thats what it solved.

Comment: I just read this whole thread to find out that this is already solved.  Please mark this as the answer so others will know that you don't need any further help.

Comment: ya i wish i could, but stackoverflow wont let me pick my own answer for atleast 2 days, after 2 days i can select my own answer lol.. maybe make a request to them they start letting people accept there own answers.

Answer (score 0):

Notice what your error says? Line 0. Now, line 0 in your callback code, is clearly error free. Therefore, according to IE, the error you have is in one of the event handlers of your elements ... like `<body onload="...">`. Check the page elements for that. (For a complete fix, drop IE and use Firefox to test your websites)

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have enough info to try to duplicate it, the best I can do is ask questions that may help you.

1. What browsers does this error appear
   on?
2. If on Firefox, have you installed
   firebug, if yes, what error is in
   the console?
3. If on IE, have you tried IE8? If
   yes, bring up the Web Developer
   plugin (for me I hit F12) and start
   debugging the javascript, and see
   what error comes up, and what line.
4. Let us know what was sent to the
   server, the response, and the
   results from debugging.
5. What is the value in `response` that
   was passed to built_list?

Otherwise it is purely guesswork.  I wonder if response.bread_crumb is null.

Comment: You didn't specify the error in firebug.  Since it isn't in the function you put code up for you may want to edit the question with better code to give more guidance.

Comment: actually that is the error from firebug, but i found the problem, but need solution, check my edited  post again please.. thank you